# Regexp for string which shouldn't contain two known chars

Tags: php, regex

For example

I have a string like `"12345%67890"`

`Regexp [^%]*` gives me `12345`.

How to get the same result, if I need to use not `"%"`, but `"<%"` for example.
Thanks a lot.

A bit more information:
I have a huge text, where I make some replacements between `%%`, like `%test%` I change to something else using `preg_match_all` and `preg_replace`, but if % was used not like a separator, everything crashes. Ex: `%test 90% test%`, so I've decided to change % to something more complicated like `<% test 90% test %>`.

Comment: have you tried /[^\<%]*/ ?

Comment: yes, it works great, but you will get the same result for following strings: "12345%67890", "12345<67890" and "12345<%67890". And I only need for the last one.

Comment: how about this  /[^(\<%)]*/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on your new information it sounds like you control the output, which makes this all kind of weird.

In any case, here's a regex that will capture the contents of the wrapper you've created:

```
<%(.+?)%>
```

Notice the `?` for a lazy match.

Code sample:

```
$string = "asdfar <%test123%>farasr%<5 sara><%90% is cool%%><%ooooaaaah%>>>%<%>%%";
preg_match_all('/<%(.+?)%>/', $string, $matches);
var_dump($matches);
```

Output:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    string(11) "<%test123%>"
    [1]=>
    string(16) "<%90% is cool%%>"
    [2]=>
    string(13) "<%ooooaaaah%>"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    string(7) "test123"
    [1]=>
    string(12) "90% is cool%"
    [2]=>
    string(9) "ooooaaaah"
  }
}
```

Comment: I use preg_match_all on this string, for a single % as separator it gives: `[0]=>12345 [1]=> [2]=>67890 [3]=>`, but for <% I got different result.

Comment: Thanks a lot! A few minutes ago I've done approximately the same thing, just (.*?) instead of (.+?). Thanks a lot once again!

Comment: But got some problems in situation like: <% test <% test 2 %> %>

Comment: Which result do you expect in that situation?

Answer (score 0):

Seems to me you should be doing a split, not a match:

```
$subject = "12345<%67890";
$result = preg_split('/<%/', $subject);
print_r($result);
```

output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 12345
    [1] => 67890
)
```

Comment: Splitting could be a good option, depending on what he's after. However using regex for a simple string split is perhaps a little overkill. `explode('<%', $subject)` would probably be more efficient.

Comment: No, it is not just about splitting string, I've added some information to the first post, I think I wasn't absolutely specific first.

Comment: Yes, that's a very different question.  You need to do a positive match on the whole kaboodle and grab the content with a capturing group, like [ohaal suggested](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16915442/20938).